# GStreamer-Unable to build pipline: no element tcppclientsrc

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gstreamer

[image] i have gone through the gstreamer tutorial from 1-5 .There developer have used static url whichis http:// but mine requirement is little different. 
below is my code which i altered in demo3 tutorial code

pipeline = gst_parse_launch("tcpclientsrc host=***.***.**.*** port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false enable-last-buffer=false", &error);

```
if (error) {

    gchar *message = g_strdup_printf("Unable to build pipeline: %s", error->message);

    g_clear_error (&error);

    [self setUIMessage:message];

    g_free (message);

    return;

}
```

but it returing an error called "Unable to build pipline: no element tcpclientsrc"

Please guide me where am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try running `gst-inspect-1.0 tcpclientsrc`, if it says no such plugin, install the `gst-plugins-base`

P.S your error says `tcppclientsrc`, it should be `tcpclientsrc`

Comment: what do you mean by running gst-inspect-1.0 tcpclientsrc , how i should perform that

Comment: Have you tried testing your pipeline with `gst-launch`, it is always a good idea to test your pipeline using the tools first, and then build them in code. Here is a [link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/gstreamer-tools.html).

Comment: I have installed gst-plugins-base and tried but it still throws same error.

Comment: What is the output of `gst-inspect-1.0 tcpclientsrc`. I am not familiar with gstreamer on ios, but on Linux, the above command when run on a Terminal must display some result.

Comment: it just show details :-       gst-inspect-1.0 tcpclientsrc
Factory Details:
  Rank                     none (0)
  Long-name                TCP client source
  Klass                    Source/Network
  Description              Receive data as a client over the network via TCP
  Author                   Thomas Vander Stichele <thomas at apestaart dot org>

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different gstreamer versions installed, maybe 0.10 and 1.0?  Does your code link with the 1.0 version?

Comment: yeah i have sorted that issue but now struggling with host id, i mean i can't set host id at run time it should be hardcoded then only it will work

Comment: What was the issue?  Why not rebuild the pipeline when a new host is to be set?